# Regex to catch period symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a condition in my javascript that is used to catch invalid data entry. Consecutive letters are not allowed, spaces are not allowed and I also don't want to allow any non-alphanumeric characters. This seems to work but for some reason the period symbol '.' is not getting caught as a non alpha-numeric.

```
if ((/\s/.test(myVar)) || (/[A-Z]{2}/.test(myVar)) || (/^[A-Z0-9]+$/.test(myVar)) ) { 
        valid = false;
}
```

Comment: `[A-Z]{2}` does *not* match consecutive letters. It matches any combination of two letters.

Comment: That's very strange testing you're doing there. The third test will return true for any string, which is only made up of uppercase letters and digits. Seems like you've got the condition inverted.

Comment: @deceze I should rephrase - tests for 2 consecutive alpha characters.

Comment: In plain English, your conditions read *if it has a space, or has any two consecutive letters, or consists only of upper case alphanumerics, it's invalid.* If you have a choice in the matter, stop enforcing any such rules on passwords to begin with.

Comment: I want the third condition to check for characters which are not alphanumeric (ignore the case-sensitivity, all alpha chars are automatically uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do:

```
if (/[A-Z]{2}|[^A-Z0-9]/.test(myVar)) { 
    valid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are quite wrong. @Deceze has explained quite nicely what kind of checks you're actually doing as opposed to what you think you're doing.

The first regex is ok, but the second one should be like this:

```
/([A-Z])\1/
```

Your regex matches any two alphas, not just two consecutive letters.

The third condition is also very strange, try this instead:

```
/[^A-Z0-9]/
```

Note that this completely eliminates the need for the first check - spaces aren't alphas nor digits.

And of course, you could combine both of those tests into a single test, but I'll leave that up to you :)